# iOS Reverse tableView sort order

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sorting, tableview

Is there a way to reverse the tableView order?

For example, I have a tableView that sorts by firstUpdated to LastUpdated. It does automatically cause its composed by plist data. But what if I want to put the newest data on top and the older on bottom?

Answer (score 6):

The other solution will work fine but this one is a bit shorter.

`NSArray *reversedArray = [[originalArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I am assuming the initial array is sorted (because it should be). Reversing a sorted array gives you a reversed and sorted array.

Comment: He is picking from p-list how you can say that array is sorted?

Comment: In order to use a plist he had to have loaded into an NSArray to begin with. In the question he states that the data is sorted firstUpdated to lastUpdated. Therefore, he is using a sorted array.

Comment: But its bad practice the good way is that we have to sort array not reverse for better result ...

Comment: Yes, the initial array is sorted.

Comment: As the plist is also sorted, as the user puts more information, it goes to the end of the plist.

Comment: The array is already sorted as Lucas said. I think you have misunderstood the problem Abhishek.

Answer (score 6):

You should sort the array you use to populate the table view.

The other two answers would work, but I have another way of doing this if you need to sort by any property of the object:

You can create a method `-sortMyArray`

and it will look like:

```
-(void)sortMyArray
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"SomeObjectSortProperty" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

    [MyArray sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [sortDescriptor release];
}
```

and of course, every time after you call this method, you need to call your table view reload data method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative (to maintain only a copy of the original array), is to use the original array and just grab objects in backwards order in the `UITableViewDataSource` functions.

Example:

`id currentObject = [originalArray objectAtIndex:(originalArray.count - indexPath.row - 1)];`

This is actually probably a better solution because you don't need to maintain 2 copies of the same data simply for reversed order.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.yourCurrentArrayOfObjects = ...;
NSMutableArray *reversedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:yourCurrentArrayOfObjects.count];
for (id object in yourCurrentArrayOfObjects.reverseObjectEnumerator)
{
    [reversedArray addObject:object];
}
self.yourCurrentArrayOfObjects = [reversedArray copy];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: it will reverse the array while he want to sort his array not reverse

Comment: "Is there a way to reverse the tableView order?" I think he does want it reversed?

Comment: I m simply saying he must be sort his array not reverse.. how can you assume that array is sorted its bad practice i just want to sort array in some order not reverse ... got my point

Answer (score 0):

You were using the array to populate the data in table view ...

Sort that array rather than sorting the table order..

Comment: it was not me who voted down. I actually voted up cause you already helped me once. But it makes sense what you said, I just don't know how do do that lol

Comment: i was not saying that you down voted..I was just concerning to that who did, cause if you got any issue then you can down vote i dond have any issue.. anyways for you just sort your array not reverse.. it will help you in future in case..

Comment: I am getting your point, listen tomorrow he add ten more elements in his p-list and now its not sorted in case what will happen.. he would have change his code again ... i just don't want it.. got my point

Comment: he is not serializing the array. It should be reloaded anytime the plist is updated.